# background image and text horizontal nav bar

Tags: html, css

I'm a student relatively new to CSS3. I'm trying to properly style a horizontal nav bar using a background image icon and text links at the block level, and to which are inline as well. Also, I'm trying to do the same on the hover states as well.

Here's a link to what I'm stuck with so far:

http://visionsic.github.io/DSW_II/test.html

```css
#aside_sect_mm {
  margin: 0px;
  background-position: 0%;
  background-color: #004E27;
  max-width: 704px;
  max-height: 100px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  position: relative;
}
#aside_sect_mm nav {
  text-align: center;
  max-width: 704px;
  width: 100%;
  max-height: 60px;
  margin-top: 0%;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
}
#aside_sect_mm nav:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
#aside_sect_mm nav ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  max-height: 100px;
  max-width: 704px;
  position: relative;
}
#aside_sect_mm nav ul li {
  font-size: 1.1em;
  font-family: "Gill Sans", "Gill Sans MT", "Myriad Pro", "DejaVu Sans Condensed", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-weight: lighter;
  text-align: center;
  list-style: none;
  line-height: 1.1em;
  position: relative;
  padding: 6.5% 0% 0% 0%;
  max-height: 60px;
  color: #FCE011;
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  min-width: 20%;
  background-color: #004E27;
  overflow: auto;
}
#aside_sect_mm nav ul li.bio_icon,
#aside_sect_mm nav ul li.stat_icon,
#aside_sect_mm nav ul li.img_icon,
#aside_sect_mm nav ul li.vid_icon,
#aside_sect_mm nav ul li.fut_icon {
  position: relative;
  max-height: 60px;
  max-width: 60px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 50% 0%;
  background-size: 40px 40px;
  display: block;
}
#aside_sect_mm nav ul li.bio_icon {
  background-image: url(../svg/bio_ore_ylw.svg);
}
#aside_sect_mm nav ul li.stat_icon {
  background-image: url(../svg/stats_ore_ylw.svg);
}
#aside_sect_mm nav ul li.img_icon {
  background-image: url(../svg/img_ore_ylw.svg);
}
#aside_sect_mm nav ul li.vid_icon {
  background-image: url(../svg/vids_ore_ylw.svg);
}
#aside_sect_mm nav ul li.fut_icon {
  background-image: url(../svg/fut_ore_ylw.svg);
}
#aside_sect_mm nav ul li.bio_icon a,
#aside_sect_mm nav ul li.stat_icon a,
#aside_sect_mm nav ul li.img_icon a,
#aside_sect_mm nav ul li.vid_icon a,
#aside_sect_mm nav ul li.fut_icon a {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  max-height: 60px;
  max-width: 60px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #F6EF1B;
}
#aside_sect_mm nav ul li.bio_icon a:hover,
#aside_sect_mm nav ul li.stat_icon a:hover,
#aside_sect_mm nav ul li.img_icon a:hover,
#aside_sect_mm nav ul li.vid_icon a:hover,
#aside_sect_mm nav ul li.fut_icon a:hover {
  position: relative;
  max-height: 60px;
  max-width: 60px;
  display: block;
  background-color: #F6EF1B;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 0%;
  text-decoration: none;
  line-height: 2.5em;
  color: #004E27;
}
#aside_sect_mm nav ul li.bio_icon a:hover {
  background-image: url(../svg/bio_ore_grn.svg);
}
#aside_sect_mm nav ul li.stat_icon a:hover {
  background-image: url(../svg/stats_ore_grn.svg);
}
#aside_sect_mm nav ul li.img_icon a:hover {
  background-image: url(../svg/img_ore_grn.svg);
}
#aside_sect_mm nav ul li.vid_icon a:hover {
  background-image: url(../svg/vids_ore_grn.svg);
}
#aside_sect_mm nav ul li.fut_icon a:hover {
  background-image: url(../svg/fut_ore_grn.svg);
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Untitled Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/test.css">
</head>

<body>
  <section id="aside_sect_mm">
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li class="bio_icon"><a href="#bio">Bio</a>
        </li>
        <li class="stat_icon"><a href="#stats">Stats</a>
        </li>
        <li class="img_icon"><a href="#images">Images</a>
        </li>
        <li class="vid_icon"><a href="#videos">Videos</a>
        </li>
        <li class="fut_icon"><a href="#future">Future</a>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </section>

</body>

</html>
```

**UPDATE:**

Ashwani corrected the positioning of the nav bar, thank you sir!
Now, I'm just trying to achieve the state to be the same by allowing the clickable hover link area to fill the whole block of each button region. The hover width is correct, but the bg image is over center of the link text. I want it to position just like in it's normal "up" state.

Here's the updated sample:

http://visionsic.github.io/DSW_II/test.html

```css
#aside_sect_mm {
  margin: 0px;
  background-position: 0%;
  background-color: #004E27;
  max-width: 704px;
  max-height: 100px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  position: relative;
}
#aside_sect_mm nav {
  text-align: center;
  max-width: 704px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin-top: 0%;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
}
#aside_sect_mm nav:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
#aside_sect_mm nav ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}
#aside_sect_mm nav ul li {
  font-size: 1.1em;
  font-family: "Gill Sans", "Gill Sans MT", "Myriad Pro", "DejaVu Sans Condensed", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-weight: lighter;
  text-align: center;
  list-style: none;
  line-height: 1.1em;
  position: relative;
  padding: 6.5% 0% 0% 0%;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  color: #FCE011;
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  min-width: 20%;
  background-color: #004E27;
  overflow: auto;
}
#aside_sect_mm nav ul li.bio_icon,
#aside_sect_mm nav ul li.stat_icon,
#aside_sect_mm nav ul li.img_icon,
#aside_sect_mm nav ul li.vid_icon,
#aside_sect_mm nav ul li.fut_icon {
  position: relative;
  max-height: 100%;
  max-width: 140.8px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 50% 0%;
  background-size: 40px 40px;
  display: block;
  overflow: auto;
}
#aside_sect_mm nav ul li.bio_icon {
  background-image: url(../svg/bio_ore_ylw.svg);
}
#aside_sect_mm nav ul li.stat_icon {
  background-image: url(../svg/stats_ore_ylw.svg);
}
#aside_sect_mm nav ul li.img_icon {
  background-image: url(../svg/img_ore_ylw.svg);
}
#aside_sect_mm nav ul li.vid_icon {
  background-image: url(../svg/vids_ore_ylw.svg);
}
#aside_sect_mm nav ul li.fut_icon {
  background-image: url(../svg/fut_ore_ylw.svg);
}
#aside_sect_mm nav ul li.bio_icon a,
#aside_sect_mm nav ul li.stat_icon a,
#aside_sect_mm nav ul li.img_icon a,
#aside_sect_mm nav ul li.vid_icon a,
#aside_sect_mm nav ul li.fut_icon a {
  clear: left;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  max-height: 60px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #F6EF1B;
  overflow: auto;
}
#aside_sect_mm nav ul li.bio_icon a:hover,
#aside_sect_mm nav ul li.stat_icon a:hover,
#aside_sect_mm nav ul li.img_icon a:hover,
#aside_sect_mm nav ul li.vid_icon a:hover,
#aside_sect_mm nav ul li.fut_icon a:hover {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-color: #F6EF1B;
  background-position: 50% 50%;
  background-size: 40px 40px;
  text-decoration: none;
  line-height: 1.1em;
  color: #004E27;
  overflow: auto;
}
#aside_sect_mm nav ul li.bio_icon a:hover {
  background-image: url(../svg/bio_ore_grn.svg);
}
#aside_sect_mm nav ul li.stat_icon a:hover {
  background-image: url(../svg/stats_ore_grn.svg);
}
#aside_sect_mm nav ul li.img_icon a:hover {
  background-image: url(../svg/img_ore_grn.svg);
}
#aside_sect_mm nav ul li.vid_icon a:hover {
  background-image: url(../svg/vids_ore_grn.svg);
}
#aside_sect_mm nav ul li.fut_icon a:hover {
  background-image: url(../svg/fut_ore_grn.svg);
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Untitled Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/test.css">
</head>

<body>
  <section id="aside_sect_mm">
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li class="bio_icon"><a href="#bio">Bio</a>
        </li>
        <li class="stat_icon"><a href="#stats">Stats</a>
        </li>
        <li class="img_icon"><a href="#images">Images</a>
        </li>
        <li class="vid_icon"><a href="#videos">Videos</a>
        </li>
        <li class="fut_icon"><a href="#future">Future</a>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </section>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: What's the question? What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

```
**you can simply use the following structure for link tag**
#aside_sect_mm nav ul li a{
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    max-height: 60px;
    /*max-width: 60px; -- remove max width*/
    /*margin: 0 auto --- if you want to use max width so you should use margin o auto*/
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #F6EF1B;
}
#aside_sect_mm nav ul li a:hover{
    background-color: #f6ef1b;
    background-position: 0 center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    color: #004e27;
    display: block;
    line-height: 2.5em;
    max-height: 60px;
    /*max-width: 60px; remove max-width*/
    position: relative;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Comment: I would definitely give you a vote up on your reply! I need to gain more reputation to do so. That css transition effect is awesome! Thank you so much!!!!

Comment: I'm trying to achieve the hover state to be the opposing colors flipped. But, you fixed the positioning of the nav buttons to be correct, like you have them now. I would like to see the hover to be a reverse of colors; a color flip on hover. The clickable region should cover the entire BLOCK area of the button.

Answer (score 0):

```
<style type="text/css">
*{
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
 -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
      box-sizing: border-box;
}
#aside_sect_mm {
    background: url("http://visionsic.github.io/DSW_II/img/mm_main_tab_c.jpg") no-repeat center center / cover;
    height: 318px;
    margin: 0;
    /*margin: 0 auto;*/ /*use this line if you want to align page horizontal  center*/
    max-width: 704px;
    position: relative;
}
#aside_sect_mm nav {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    top: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
#aside_sect_mm nav::after {
    clear: both;
    content: " ";
    display: table;
}
#aside_sect_mm nav ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    list-style: none;
}
#aside_sect_mm .icon {
    background-color: #004e27;
    float: left;
    font-family: "Gill Sans","Gill Sans MT","Myriad Pro","DejaVu Sans Condensed",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
    overflow: auto;
    text-align: center;
    width: 20%;
}
#aside_sect_mm .icon a{
    background-position: 50% 10%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 100px 40px;
    display: block;
    padding: 50px 0 5px 0;
    color: #fce011;
    font-weight: normal;
    text-decoration: none;
}
#aside_sect_mm .icon.bio_icon a{
    background-image: url("http://visionsic.github.io/DSW_II/svg/bio_ore_ylw.svg");
    background-position: 62% 10%;
}
#aside_sect_mm .icon.stat_icon a{
    background-image: url("http://visionsic.github.io/DSW_II/svg/stats_ore_ylw.svg");
}
#aside_sect_mm .icon.img_icon a{
    background-image: url("http://visionsic.github.io/DSW_II/svg/img_ore_ylw.svg");
}
#aside_sect_mm .icon.vid_icon a{
    background-image: url("http://visionsic.github.io/DSW_II/svg/vids_ore_ylw.svg");
}
#aside_sect_mm .icon.fut_icon a{
    background-image: url("http://visionsic.github.io/DSW_II/svg/fut_ore_ylw.svg");
}
#aside_sect_mm .icon.bio_icon:hover a{
    background-image: url("http://visionsic.github.io/DSW_II/svg/bio_ore_grn.svg");
}
#aside_sect_mm .icon.stat_icon:hover a{
    background-image: url("http://visionsic.github.io/DSW_II/svg/stats_ore_grn.svg");
}
#aside_sect_mm .icon.img_icon:hover a{
    background-image: url("http://visionsic.github.io/DSW_II/svg/img_ore_grn.svg");
}
#aside_sect_mm .icon.vid_icon:hover a{
    background-image: url("http://visionsic.github.io/DSW_II/svg/vids_ore_grn.svg");
}
#aside_sect_mm .icon.fut_icon:hover a{
    background-image: url("http://visionsic.github.io/DSW_II/svg/fut_ore_grn.svg");
}
#aside_sect_mm .icon:hover a {
    background-color: #f6ef1b;
    color: #004e27;
    -moz-transition: background-color 1s ease 0s;
  -webkit-transition: background-color 1s ease 0s;
          transition: background-color 1s ease 0s;
}
</style> 
<section id="aside_sect_mm">
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li class="bio_icon icon"><a href="#bio">Bio</a></li>
            <li class="stat_icon icon"><a href="#stats">Stats</a></li>
            <li class="img_icon icon"><a href="#images">Images</a></li>
            <li class="vid_icon icon"><a href="#videos">Videos</a></li>
            <li class="fut_icon icon"><a href="#future">Future</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</section>
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Thanks for suggesting me to use html/css code here instead of link. :)